# Is it safe to use single ScheduledExecutorService to run more than one task?

Tags: java, scheduling, scheduledexecutorservice

I would like to use `ScheduledExecutorService` to export some data in scheduled manner.

In my code below I have called 2 different task in 2 different time intervals. There will be a chance where multiple task is schedule in 1 `ScheduledExecutorService` when user creates multiple scheduling to export multiple data(different reports).

1. Is it safe to use single `ScheduledExecutorService` to run more than one task?
2. Is it possible to stop one of the task(Eg. `service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable2, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`) if user deletes specific scheduling?

   ```
   public static void main(String... args) {        
         Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {          public void run() {
       // task to run goes here
         System.out.println("Every 5 sec: "+ new java.util.Date());

     }
   };

   Runnable runnable2 = new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
           // task to run goes here
             System.out.println("Every 10 sec: "+ new java.util.Date());
         }
       };
   ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
   service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   service.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnable2, 0, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
   }
   ```

Comment: This works even with one thread, but you can start as many threads as there are task to improve timing.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik- Thanks. Will I be able to stop one of the task if I use this method of scheduling?

Comment: that can be really trouble , you might have to create custom `Runnable` in order to manually interrupt them. check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418033/java-executors-how-can-i-stop-submitted-tasks) , it refers to a callable , but you would do it in the same way as you are keeping the references to the `runnable`s instead of the `Future`

Comment: Thanks @AntJavaDev..Got better understanding after viewing the post you have mentioned

Comment: You will have no trouble canceling an individual schedule, if that's what you asked.