# Cancel superseded task in ThreadPool in Java/Kotlin

Tags: java, concurrency, locking, kotlin

I'm trying to figure out how to cancel a task in a `ThreadPool` if a new tasks comes along that supersedes it.  I have some classes similar to this:

```
class RenderableThing {
    private val lock = ReentrantLock()
    fun lock(interrupt: Boolean) {
        if (lock.isLocked && interrupt) {
            // How do I interrupt the thread that has the lock?
        }
        lock.lock()
    }
    fun unlock() = lock.unlock()

    fun cache() = Cached()
    inner class Cached()
}

class BackgroundStuff(threads: Int) {
    val pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads)!!

    fun doBackgroundStuff(thing: RenderableThing): Future<Stuff> {
        val cache = thing.cache()
        return pool.submit {
            try {
                thing.lock()
                // Do long running I/O task on cache
            } finally {
                thing.unlock()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, if the same `RenderableThing` gets submitted to `doBackgroundStuff` (a change was made and needs to be saved to disk), I would like to be able to able to cancel the `Future` of the previous submission (since it's now out of date and will be overwritten, there's no reason to wait for it to finish anymore). The problem is, the locking is taking place inside the future that doesn't exist yet.

I know you're never supposed to force kill a locked thread (I don't even know how since it's a `ReentrantLock`), so what is the proper way to do this?

**Edit**: My question is different from [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418033/java-executors-how-can-i-stop-submitted-tasks) as I don't have access to the future to cancel it (the lock isn't put in place till the `ThreadPool` picks it up, and by that point the `thing` could have been submitted multiple times, and I don't know which would own the lock). If I did it would be a piece of cake (the code to handle interruption is already in place). How should I change my code to get a reference to the future (or even the thread) that owns the lock?

Comment: Don't you know `Future` has a method called `cancel`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java Executors: how can I stop submitted tasks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418033/java-executors-how-can-i-stop-submitted-tasks)

Comment: I am aware, see my edit

Comment: Isn't storing all references in a set and calling `cancel` on each of them good enough? Or are you worrying about the tiny overhead caused?

Comment: How would I do that without potentially cancelling the latest submitted one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just wondering if this piece of code works:

```
//...
fun doBackgroundStuff(thing: RenderableThing): Future<Stuff> {
    L.L.get(thing)?.cancel(true)
    val cache = thing.cache()
    val f = pool.submit {
        try {
            thing.lock()
            // Do long running I/O task on cache
        } finally {
            thing.unlock()
        }
    }
    L.L.put(thing, f)
    return f
}
//...

object L {
    val L: IdentityHashMap<RenderableThing, Future<Stuff>>  ? = IdentityHashMap<>()
}
```

Comment: No, that would keep all but one `RenderableThing`, where I only want to remove it if it is the same one. I already tried similar code (but putting it in `RenderableThing` to solve this issue), but ran into issues since the delayed locking means anything could have happened in the meantime.

Comment: Actually, Modifying your code to mix it with what I was doing earlier might just solve my problem. Let me run some tests.

Comment: @RuckusT-Boom Updated.