# Writing a multithreaded mapping iterator in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I've got a general purpose mapping iterator: something like this:

```
class Mapper<F, T> implements Iterator<T> {

  private Iterator<F> input;
  private Action<F, T> action;

  public Mapper(input, action) {...}

  public boolean hasNext() {
    return input.hasNext();
  }

  public T next() {
    return action.process(input.next());
  }
}
```

Now, given that action.process() can be time-consuming, I want to gain performance by using multiple threads to process items from the input in parallel. I want to allocate a pool of N worker threads and allocate items to these threads for processing. This should happen "behind the scenes" so the client code just sees an Iterator. The code should avoid holding either the input or the output sequence in memory.

To add a twist, I want two versions of the solution, one which retains order (the final iterator delivers items in the same order as the input iterator) and one of which does not necessarily retain order (each output item is delivered as soon as it is available).

I've sort-of got this working but the code seems convoluted and unreliable and I'm not confident it's using best practice.

Any suggestions on the simplest and most robust way of implementing this? I'm looking for something that works in JDK 6, and I want to avoid introducing dependencies on external libraries/frameworks if possible.

Comment: I don't know the answer, but this is a very good problem to pursue.  There go my night's sleep as I code this one.  P.S. Although very passionate about programming, I am a bit slow at it, as I grasp problems and come up with solutions slowly, as opposed to the rockstar programmers who can produce a bubble sort in minutes.  Hence full night.

Comment: "...so the client code just sees an Iterator..."  What if you implemented `Iterator<Future<T>>` instead of `Iterator<T>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd use a thread pool for the threads and a `BlockingQueue` to feed out from the pool.

This seems to work with my simple test cases.

```
interface Action<F, T> {

    public T process(F f);

}

class Mapper<F, T> implements Iterator<T> {

    protected final Iterator<F> input;
    protected final Action<F, T> action;

    public Mapper(Iterator<F> input, Action<F, T> action) {
        this.input = input;
        this.action = action;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return input.hasNext();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return action.process(input.next());
    }
}

class ParallelMapper<F, T> extends Mapper<F, T> {

    // The pool.
    final ExecutorService pool;
    // The queue.
    final BlockingQueue<T> queue;
    // The next one to deliver.
    private T next = null;

    public ParallelMapper(Iterator<F> input, Action<F, T> action, int threads, int queueLength) {
        super(input, action);
        // Start my pool.
        pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
        // And the queue.
        queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(queueLength);
    }

    class Worker implements Runnable {

        final F f;
        private T t;

        public Worker(F f) {
            this.f = f;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                queue.put(action.process(f));
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Not sure what you can do here.
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        // All done if delivered it and the input is empty and the queue is empty and the threads are finished.
        while (next == null && (input.hasNext() || !queue.isEmpty() || !pool.isTerminated())) {
            // First look in the queue.
            next = queue.poll();
            if (next == null) {
                // Queue empty.
                if (input.hasNext()) {
                    // Start a new worker.
                    pool.execute(new Worker(input.next()));
                }
            } else {
                // Input exhausted - shut down the pool - unless we already have.
                if (!pool.isShutdown()) {
                    pool.shutdown();
                }
            }
        }
        return next != null;
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        T n = next;
        if (n != null) {
            // Delivered that one.
            next = null;
        } else {
            // Fails.
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        }
        return n;
    }
}

public void test() {
    List<Integer> data = Arrays.asList(5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0);
    System.out.println("Data");
    for (Integer i : Iterables.in(data)) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    Action<Integer, Integer> action = new Action<Integer, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer process(Integer f) {
            try {
                // Wait that many seconds.
                Thread.sleep(1000L * f);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                // Just give up.
            }
            // Return it unchanged.
            return f;
        }

    };
    System.out.println("Processed");
    for (Integer i : Iterables.in(new Mapper<Integer, Integer>(data.iterator(), action))) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }
    System.out.println("Parallel Processed");
    for (Integer i : Iterables.in(new ParallelMapper<Integer, Integer>(data.iterator(), action, 2, 2))) {
        System.out.println(i);
    }

}
```

Note: `Iterables.in(Iterator<T>)` just creates an `Iterable<T>` that encapsulates the passed `Iterator<T>`.

For your in-order one you could process `Pair<Integer,F>` and use a `PriorityQueue` for the thread output. You could then arrange to pull them in order.

Comment: Many thanks. I've picked up the basic idea from this answer and combined ingredients from some of the other answers, I'll show my own solution below.

Answer (score 3):

I dont think it can work with parallel threads because hasNext() may return true but by the time the thread calls next() there may be no more elements. It is better to use only next() which will return null when theres no more elements

Answer (score 3):

OK, thanks everyone. This is what I've done.

First I wrap my ItemMappingFunction in a Callable:

```
private static class CallableAction<F extends Item, T extends Item> 
implements Callable<T> {
    private ItemMappingFunction<F, T> action;
    private F input;
    public CallableAction(ItemMappingFunction<F, T> action, F input) {
            this.action = action;
            this.input = input;
    }
    public T call() throws XPathException {
            return action.mapItem(input);
    }
}
```

I described my problem in terms of the standard Iterator class, but actually I'm using my own SequenceIterator interface, which has a single next() method that returns null at end-of-sequence.

I declare the class in terms of the "ordinary" mapping iterator like this:

```
public class MultithreadedMapper<F extends Item, T extends Item> extends Mapper<F, T> {

    private ExecutorService service;
    private BlockingQueue<Future<T>> resultQueue = 
        new LinkedBlockingQueue<Future<T>>();
```

On initialization I create the service and prime the queue:

```
public MultithreadedMapper(SequenceIterator base, ItemMappingFunction<F, T> action) throws XPathException {
        super(base, action);

        int maxThreads = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        maxThreads = maxThreads > 0 ? maxThreads : 1;
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(maxThreads);

        // prime the queue
        int n = 0;
        while (n++ < maxThreads) {
            F item = (F) base.next();
            if (item == null) {
                return;
            }
            mapOneItem(item);
        }
    }
```

Where mapOneItem is:

```
private void mapOneItem(F in) throws XPathException {
    Future<T> future = service.submit(new CallableAction(action, in));
    resultQueue.add(future);
}
```

When the client asks for the next item, I first submit the next input item to the executor service, then get the next output item, waiting for it to be available if necessary:

```
    public T next() throws XPathException {
        F nextIn = (F)base.next();
        if (nextIn != null) {
            mapOneItem(nextIn);
        }
        try {
            Future<T> future = resultQueue.poll();
            if (future == null) {
                service.shutdown();
                return null;
            } else {
                return future.get();
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new XPathException(e);
        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
            if (e.getCause() instanceof XPathException) {
                throw (XPathException)e.getCause();
            }
            throw new XPathException(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Using a `LinkedBlockingQueue` you may find that if the supply is much faster than the pool can handle you could end up with too may entries in the queue. Obviously this depends on your environment.

Comment: Using `resultQueue.poll()` you could find that a number of threads are in progress but none of them have as yet posted anything into the queue. Looks like you would prematurely exit. This is why I use a `while` loop in my `hasNext`. **Ooops** sorry - I didnt notice you fill the result queue with `Futures` - scratch that one.

Answer (score 0):

In order for `action.process` to be called in parallel, `next()` would need to be called in parallel. That's not good practice. Instead you could use a [ExecutorCompletionService](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorCompletionService.html).

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/1228445/360211

Unfortunately I believe this only gives you the option to preserve order.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the JDK executor framework. Create tasks (Runnables) for you actions. Run them in parallel using a thread pool if needed or in sequence if not. Give the tasks sequence numbers if you need order in the end. But as noted in other answers, the iterator does not work very well for you since calling next() is generally not done in parallel.. So do you even need an iterator or just to get the tasks processed?