# Writing a multithreaded mapping IEnumerator in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

This is related to [Writing a multithreaded mapping iterator in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27796032/writing-a-multithreaded-mapping-iterator-in-java) but I now want to do the same thing in C#.

I have an `IEnumerator<F>` defining a sequence of input items, and a `Function<F, T>` that I want to apply to each item; I want to deliver the results of these functions as an `IEnumerator<T>`. And I want it to be multithreaded, so that the functions are applied in different threads (we can assume the function is expensive to compute). I'm flexible about things like scheduling policies.

How would you suggest implementing this in C#?

Comment: Use AsParallel()

Comment: Side note: it is very unusual to look for input/output to be `IEnumerator<T>` instead of `IEnumerable<T>`. Since duplicate addresses regular inputs it does not seem to actually be duplicate of *this* question as asked... Could you please clarify if `IEnumerator` requirement is critical so question can be re-opened if needed?

Comment: My question isn't an exact duplicate (for example, I need to retain ordering) but the cited answer has pointed me in the right direction, so I don't need it re-opened, thank you. I do need to work with `IEnumerator<T>` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` because some inputs may be streamed such that I can only read them once.

Comment: I am asking for this to be reopened since the cited duplicate requires an IEnumerable rather than an IEnumerator as input.